# TypeScript: How to tell TypeScript in which If case I am?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, react-tsx, typescript-types, typescript2.8

I'm building a React Native application using TypeScript. My startup recently switched to TypeScript from JavaScript and I'm migrating the code.

I have a `<FlatList />` that consists of two types of venues: Restaurant and Bar. Restaurant and Bar share some properties, but they also don't. For example the property `servesFood` is unique to Restaurants.

The `renderItem` function looks like this:

```
renderItem = ({ item }: { item: Restaurant | Bar }) => {
  return item.servesFood ? (
    // ... Restaurant code
  ) : (
    // ... Bar code
  )
```

The problem is, that in the condition for this ternary operator TypeScript throws the error:

```
Property 'servesFood' does not exist on type 'Restaurant | Bar'.
  Property 'servesFood' does not exist on type 'Bar'
```

Furthermore in the type specific code when accessing type specific properties there are also linting errors.

**Note:** For various reason I can't let them share a property and set one to true on the `first` one and to `false` on the other one.

So how can I tell TypeScript that in the one part of the If clause / ternary operator item is of type Restaurant and in the other item is of type bar, so that these linting errors go away.

Comment: what about the following syntax? : `renderItem = (item: Restaurant | Bar) => { return ...}`

Comment: This doesn't look to be 'OOPish'. What about both `Restaurant` and `Bar` implementing a common interface with a method `render()`. Both classes would have their own implementation or the `render()`. Then this method would simply be referred in the `renderItem`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a type guard to narrow the type of the parameter.

You can use discriminated unions based on the `servesFood` field:

```
interface Restaurant{
    servesFood: true
}
interface Bar {
  servesFood?: false
}
const renderItem = ({ item }: { item: Restaurant | Bar }) => {
      return item.servesFood ? (
        // ... Restaurant code
      ) : (
        // ... Bar code
      )
```

Or if the interfaces do not share `servesFood` you can use an `in` type guard

```
interface Restaurant{
    servesFood: true
}
interface Bar {
  drinks: true
}
const renderItem = ({ item }: { item: Restaurant | Bar }) => {
      return 'servesFood' in item ? (
        item.servesFood
      ) : (
        // ... Bar code
        item.drinks
      );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a simple compare the key/value of the object so you can know if the property servesFood exists for the current item. If the vaule is `null` it means that `item` doesn't contains the property `servesFood`
Something like this:

```
renderItem = ({ item }: { item: Restaurant | Bar }) => {
  return ((item["servesFood"] != null) ? (
    // ... Restaurant code, it exists the property servesFood
  ) : (
    // ... Bar code, it doesn't exists the property servesFood so it is null
  ))
```